# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character?

Tags: regex, python-2.6, non-ascii-characters

I'm trying to pass big strings of random html through regular expressions and my Python 2.6 script is choking on this:

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character

I traced it back to a trademark superscript on the end of this word: Protection™ -- I do not need to capture the non-ascii stuff, but it is a nuisance and I expect to encounter it more in the future.

Is there a module to process non-ascii characters? or, what is the best way to handle/escape non-ascii stuff in python?

Thanks!
Full error:

```
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_untitled (__main__.Untitled)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python26\Test2.py", line 26, in test_untitled
    ofile.write(Test + '\n')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2122' in position 1005: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Full Script:

```
from selenium import selenium
import unittest, time, re, csv, logging

class Untitled(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.selenium = selenium("localhost", 4444, "*firefox", "http://www.BaseDomain.com/")
        self.selenium.start()
        self.selenium.set_timeout("90000")

    def test_untitled(self):
        sel = self.selenium
        spamReader = csv.reader(open('SubDomainList.csv', 'rb'))
        for row in spamReader:
            sel.open(row[0])
            time.sleep(10)
            Test = sel.get_text("//html/body/div/table/tbody/tr/td/form/div/table/tbody/tr[7]/td")
            Test = Test.replace(",","")
            Test = Test.replace("\n", "")
            ofile = open('TestOut.csv', 'ab')
            ofile.write(Test + '\n')
            ofile.close()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.selenium.stop()
        self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Easy Q: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652904/easy-q-unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Total repetition of your other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652904/easy-q-unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character) (though here you finally deign to show us CODE from the start, wow!-).  Answer is still identical: instead of

```
        ofile.write(Test + '\n')
```

do

```
        ofile.write(Test.encode('utf8') + '\n')
```

why do you keep repeating this Q, BTW?!

Comment: I figured this is how I should have asked the question in the first place.  Much easier for you to answer clearly.  Which you did. Thanks Alex!