# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character when trying a HTTP POST in Python

Tags: python, unicode, ascii, http-post

I'm trying to do a HTTP POST with a unicode string (u'\xe4\xf6\xfc') as a parameter in Python, but I receive the following error:

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character

This is to the code used to make the HTTP POST (with httplib2)

```
 http = httplib2.Http()  
 userInfo = [('Name', u'\xe4\xf6\xfc')]
 data = urlencode(userInfo)

 resp, content = http.request(url, 'POST', body=data)
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You cannot POST Python Unicode objects directly. You should encode it as a UTF-8 string first:

```
name = u'\xe4\xf6\xfc'.encode('utf-8')
userInfo = [('Name', name)]
```

Comment: Had some problem with the encoding earlier, but then i did it inline. Like this:

userInfo = [('Name', u'\xe4\xf6\xfc'.encode('utf-8'))]

Anyway thanks for a quick response

Comment: Its very similar question of this post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652904/easy-q-unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character

Comment: It would be helpful if the documentation for httplib2 and httplib mentioned this constraint.