# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, unicode, export-to-csv

I'am trying to export as csv a pandas dataframe with the function:

```
outcome.to_csv("/Users/john/out_1.csv")
```

I get the following error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 191: ordinal not in range(128)
```

how do I go to position 191 to check what's wrong?

Many thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of ["UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652904/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character)

Comment: @johnred it's position 191 in a string that is in your DataFrame.  Perhaps you could put the whole stack trace, the DataFrame itself?

Comment: Could you try adding encoding='utf-8' to the function and see if that works? Eg outcome.to_csv("/Users/john/out_1.csv", encoding="utf-8")

Comment: if you open an ipython console and type: `print u'\u2019'` you will see what kind of character it is you are looking for. You should probably just start using python3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    outcome.to_csv("/Users/john/out_1.csv",encoding="utf-8")
```

On referring to the documentation of pandas.to_csv, we have the following details. It seems that for Python 2.7 the default is "ascii" which needs to be overridden to "utf-8"

**encoding : string, optional**

> A string representing the encoding to use in the output file, defaults
>   to ‘ascii’ on Python 2 and ‘utf-8’ on Python 3.